# Declination calculation

Tags: orbit, satellite, declination, right-ascension

My task is to calculate current declination and right ascension for some artificial Earth satellite. For example ISS.

I am using latest TLE data for extracting keplerian orbital elements and then calculate current cartesian orbital state vectors in ECI frame. 
From the position vector I directly calculate declination and right ascension, using cartesian to spherical coordinates conversion.

Right ascension gets calculated correctly but I am having problems getting the same result for declination as the one displayed by satellite trackers.

Speaking of satellite trackers, I don't understand how is their declination value even correct.

Declination is an angle measured north or south of the celestial equator.
[image: declination visually]

Celestial equator of course is on the same plane as the equator of Earth.

Then how is it possible that, when a satellite (ISS in this example) is almost directly above Earth's equator, satellite trackers calculate declination to be around -29° ?

[image: tracker 1]
[image: tracker 2]
[image: tracker 3]

Shouldn't the declination angle be zero? 
My calculations for this "ISS above equator" example did give declination to be close to 0°.

Who is doing the calculations wrong and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting parallax.

Something which is very distant and lies on the celestial equator will have a declination of 0°, but if it is nearby then its declination will only be 0° to an observer located along Earth's equator.

From your location in Zagreb, something like the ISS, even if it is crossing Earth's equator at a longitude of ~16° will appear to be in the southern sky, and your declination coordinate will likely be south of 0°.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me finally pinpoint the essence of the problem. However, I knew there would have to be some corrections for locating the satellite in observer's frame (altitude and azimuth coordinates) because of the fact that satellite isn't a very distant object, but I thought that right ascension and declination were in earth-centered-inertial frame, spherical equivalent of cartesian position vector, independent of the observer's location. "Declination in astronomy is comparable to geographic latitude, projected onto the celestial sphere" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination

Comment: The software routines by D. Vallado may come in useful to cross-check the parallax correction described by @Mick.
https://celestrak.com/software/vallado-sw.asp

Comment: @Vekszor For distant objects that is certainly true but on Solar System scales corrections do need to be made for the observer location, and for Earth-orbit position calculations even more so.